# Print duration with an add-in which changes fonts

Tags: c#, fonts, ms-word

I'm creating an add-in for word which change one font to another one just before printing.
Everything works well but It takes five minutes to print a page.

I'm using Range.Font.Name to change the font for each character using the font I want to replace.

How could I accelerate the process in order to have a normal printing time?

Comment: If you're looping each character, assigning the font, then having to wait for Word to recalculate the page layout based on that change there's nothing you can do to speed things up. Do you really need to do it character-by-character? The correct way to format a Word document is to use *styles*. Then the definition of a style can be changed which will "propagate" the changed font in one action throughout the entire document. *THAT* would be the most efficient method for what you describe.

Comment: I need to do it without _italic_ styles because if the user changes the font for some characters in a styled paragraph, I don't want my add-in to change these characters. I must check for each character.

Comment: Mmm. Ideally the user would apply other formatting using character styles. Then it wouldn't be affected by your changing the definition of the paragraph style... But training users to do that kind of thing is an uphill battle. So. Question about concept - not suggesting you *code* exactly this: As an end-user, if you were to hold the SHIFT key and use Right-Arrow to extend the selection to the last character with "other" formatting, then apply the font change, would that be acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to reduce the time needed to print by using a "foreach" loop instead of a "for"